# Turkish delight sauce or syrup

Tags: syrup

I want to make a turkish delight syrup for topping purposes! So i can pour it over my ice cream! Any idea on how to make this?

Answer (score 1):

Turkish delight is simply syrup cooked with starch and flavoring until it has the texture we know. If you want the same taste but in a liquid form, take any standard recipe and leave out as much starch as you want, possibly even all of it.